USBPcap tool and Wireshark cannot find the Yubikey
I want to analyse some APDUs from the Yubikey. For that I am trying to use USBPcap tool along with Wireshark in Windows environment to capture the USB traces. The USBPcap tool is installed from the Wireshark installation menu. But the Yubikey is not found by the USBPcap tool. I couldn't find any traces in the Wireshark capture for the Yubikey. Even when I run the USBPcapCMD.exe tool separately, the Yubikey is not listed.
Can anyone please let me know why is this happening? Is there anything missing in the setup? Or is there any other tool that can do the same?
Thanks in advance.
